# Could not create message from InputStream: Invalid Content-Type:application/json. for the Rest webservice in Spring Boot application

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I have 2 controllers that accept the same parameters and return the same type value like that:

```
@Slf4j
@Getter
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/services")
public class ServicesController {

    @PostMapping
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
    public ServiceDTO create(@RequestBody ServiceCreateDTO vo) throws BaseException {
        return serviceService.create(vo, true);
    }
```

and

```
@Slf4j
@Getter
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/service")
public class ServiceController {

    @PostMapping
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
    public ServiceDTO create(@RequestBody ServiceCreateDTO vo) throws BaseException {
        return serviceService.create(vo, false);
    }
```

so in the next layer they just use the same service and have just one parameter different to be passed into the service call. The service initialization is the same on both controllers:

```
 private ServiceService serviceService;

 private ServiceOptionService serviceOptionService;

 @Autowired
 public ServiceController(ServiceService serviceService, ServiceOptionService serviceOptionService) {
        this.serviceService = serviceService;
        this.serviceOptionService = serviceOptionService;
    }
```

so, when requesting `/service` I'm getting the expected result, while when requesting `/services`, I'm getting this error. It is uneasy to explain, as all the settings are all the same for the both controllers.

```
 ERROR io.undertow.request - UT005023: Exception handling request to /billing/service/services
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.ws.soap.SoapMessageCreationException: Could not create message from InputStream: Invalid Content-Type:application/json. Is this an error message instead of a SOAP response?; nested exception is com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj.SOAPExceptionImpl: Invalid Content-Type:application/json. Is this an error message instead of a SOAP response?
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1013)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:908)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:665)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:750)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:74)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:129)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.AbstractRequestLoggingFilter.doFilterInternal(AbstractRequestLoggingFilter.java:262)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:118)
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
        at net.bull.javamelody.MonitoringFilter.doFilter(MonitoringFilter.java:239)
        at net.bull.javamelody.MonitoringFilter.doFilter(MonitoringFilter.java:215)
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
        at org.springframework.boot.actuate.web.trace.servlet.HttpTraceFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpTraceFilter.java:88)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:118)
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:320)
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:127)
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:91)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:119)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
        at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
        at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:170)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
        at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
        at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:74)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:118)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
        at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
        at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:118)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:215)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:357)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:270)
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:118)
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:92)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:118)
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:93)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:118)
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
        at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.filterAndRecordMetrics(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:114)
        at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:104)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:118)
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:118)
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler.handleRequest(FilterHandler.java:84)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletChain$1.handleRequest(ServletChain.java:68)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.RedirectDirHandler.handleRequest(RedirectDirHandler.java:68)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:132)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)
        at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
        at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)
        at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:60)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:77)
        at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:43)
        at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
        at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:269)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$100(ServletInitialHandler.java:78)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:133)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:130)
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:48)
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:249)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:78)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:99)
        at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:376)
        at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:830)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused by: org.springframework.ws.soap.SoapMessageCreationException: Could not create message from InputStream: Invalid Content-Type:application/json. Is this an error message instead of a SOAP response?; nested exception is com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj.SOAPExceptionImpl: Invalid Content-Type:application/json. Is this an error message instead of a SOAP response?
        at org.springframework.ws.soap.saaj.SaajSoapMessageFactory.createWebServiceMessage(SaajSoapMessageFactory.java:218)
        at org.springframework.ws.soap.saaj.SaajSoapMessageFactory.createWebServiceMessage(SaajSoapMessageFactory.java:62)
        at org.springframework.ws.transport.AbstractWebServiceConnection.receive(AbstractWebServiceConnection.java:92)
        at org.springframework.ws.transport.support.WebServiceMessageReceiverObjectSupport.handleConnection(WebServiceMessageReceiverObjectSupport.java:87)
        at org.springframework.ws.transport.http.WebServiceMessageReceiverHandlerAdapter.handle(WebServiceMessageReceiverHandlerAdapter.java:61)
        at org.springframework.ws.transport.http.MessageDispatcherServlet.doService(MessageDispatcherServlet.java:293)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1005)
        ... 98 common frames omitted
Caused by: com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj.SOAPExceptionImpl: Invalid Content-Type:application/json. Is this an error message instead of a SOAP response?
        at com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj.soap.MessageImpl.identifyContentType(MessageImpl.java:740)
        at com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj.soap.MessageImpl.<init>(MessageImpl.java:331)
        at com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj.soap.ver1_1.Message1_1Impl.<init>(Message1_1Impl.java:81)
        at com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj.soap.ver1_1.SOAPMessageFactory1_1Impl.createMessage(SOAPMessageFactory1_1Impl.java:81)
        at org.springframework.ws.soap.saaj.SaajSoapMessageFactory.createWebServiceMessage(SaajSoapMessageFactory.java:190)
        ... 104 common frames omitted
```

What could be the difference of the different behavior? I believe, it is ok to have the same method signature except the url in the different controllers, so what else may be the cause?

If I replace `/services` with `/servics` in my controller it starts working, while `/services` still accepting the query and gives the same output to the stacktrace. But it isn't actually configured in my controllers elsewhere, probably comes with some library, how to find that sort of "effective controllers"?

There is also context-path configuration:

```
server:
  port: 8072
  servlet:
    context-path: /billing/service
    path: /billing/service
```

Gradle dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-webflux'
    compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-rest'
    compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-mail'
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa') {
        exclude group: 'org.hibernate', module: 'hibernate-entitymanager'
    }
    compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator'
    compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-undertow'
    compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-oauth2-resource-server'
    compile 'org.springframework.security:spring-security-oauth2-jose:5.2.1.RELEASE'
    compile 'org.springframework.security:spring-security-oauth2-core:5.2.1.RELEASE'

    compile 'org.springframework.kafka:spring-kafka:2.2.7.RELEASE'

    compile 'io.projectreactor:reactor-core:3.2.12.RELEASE'

    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.10+'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.10+'
    testAnnotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.10+'

    compile 'org.postgresql:postgresql:42.2.8'
    compile 'com.zaxxer:HikariCP:3.4.0'
    //compile 'org.flywaydb:flyway-core:5.2.4'

    compile 'org.hibernate:hibernate-core:5.4.10.Final'
    compile 'org.hibernate:hibernate-ehcache:5.4.10.Final'
    compile 'org.hibernate.javax.persistence:hibernate-jpa-2.2-api:1.0.0.Beta2'

    //compile 'net.bull.javamelody:javamelody-core:1.76.0'
    compile 'net.bull.javamelody:javamelody-spring-boot-starter:1.79.0'

    compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.9'
    compile "org.apache.commons:commons-compress:1.19"
    compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-collections4:4.4'

    compile ('io.springfox:springfox-swagger2:2.9.2') {
        exclude module: 'swagger-annotations'
        exclude module: 'swagger-models'
    }
    compile 'io.swagger:swagger-annotations:1.5.23'
    compile 'io.swagger:swagger-models:1.5.23'
    compile 'io.springfox:springfox-swagger-ui:2.9.2'

    compile 'rf.dom.billing:billing-model:RELEASE.2.2.3'
    compile 'rf.dom.billing:billing-common:RELEASE.1.0.6'
    compile 'rf.dom.billing:billing-tracking:RELEASE.1.1.8'
    compile 'rf.dom.billing:billing-1c-integration:RELEASE.0.0.3'
    compile 'rf.dom.billing:billing-docstore-integration:1.0.3'

    /*Cloud start*/
    compile 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-config:2.1+'
    compile 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter:2.1+'
    /*compile 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client:2+'*/
    compile 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-config-client:2.1+'
    /*Cloud end*/

    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/jcifs/jcifs
//    compile group: 'jcifs', name: 'jcifs', version: '1.3.17'
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.codelibs/jcifs
    compile group: 'org.codelibs', name: 'jcifs', version: '2.1.13'
    compile 'com.ibm.icu:icu4j:66.1'

    testCompile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
    testCompile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-undertow'
    testCompile 'org.testng:testng:6.14.3'
    testCompile 'org.powermock:powermock-api-mockito2:2.0.2'
    testCompile 'com.opentable.components:otj-pg-embedded:0.13.1'
    testCompile 'org.flywaydb:flyway-core:5.2.4'
}
```

Comment: You are using Spring WebServices **not** Spring MVC. So it tries to get SOAP and it gets JSON.

Comment: I'm actually haven't configured /services controller to do that. Note the main condition of the question, /service works fine with the rest json and it has the same configuration. So what is the magic intersepts /services call without xplicit controller configuration for that?

Comment: In the Java code you have "/service" and "/services" in the @RequestMapping but in the stacktrace we see "/billing/service/services", are you sure you don't have some confusion in the URL paths of your testing ?

Comment: Your stacktrace clearly indicates the request is handled by the `MessageDispatcherServlet` not the `DispatcherServlet`. No matter how many annotation changes you are going to make on yoru controllers it still will go to the `MessgeDispatcherServlet` (which is for Spring WS and SOAP WebServices).

Comment: @M.Deinum why MessageDispatcherServlet can intercept that?

Comment: @p3consulting there is a context-path configuration, added the detail to the question

Comment: Because you configured it like that.. The `MessageDispatcherServlet` by default listens to `/services/*` if IIRC. Not sure why you even have that, do you do anything with SOAP in your project? If not why is then `spring-boot-starter-web-services` on your path? Als your path mapping is weird as well as it will lead to a path of `/billing/service/billing/service` to be able to access the `DispatcherServlet`.

Comment: @M.Deinum probably it was introduced with the starter in depedency, but I actually don't have it as the explicit dependency and never configured that. I have added the dependencies to the question.

Comment: @M.Deinum is `server.servlet.context-path` setting is applied to `MessageDispatcherServlet` too?

Comment: Not sure if that is applied, nonetheless the stacktace is pretty clear and there is the `MessageDispatcherServlet` so something must be pulling it in. Something is also weird in your dependencies as you both have web and webflux as a dependency.